# Table in Database, where the combination of two is unique but either of them isn't

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am just learning programming and I am not really good at databases. I am trying to make a University Management Website.

So I have to make a table with columns - teacher, class, period, day. If there are 5 periods a day, then there are 30 periods each week (6X5). And if there are 10 classes, there are 300 combinations.

What I need is the combination of day, period and classes to be unique, that is they provide a result as just one teacher. So that two different teachers are not assigned to the same time slot in the same day to the same class.

How could I make such an arrangement to get the desired result? I am using MySQL as the database. I thought of splitting it up into more columns but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably control this from your web app rather than in the database. So when you are looking to assign a teacher a class on a particular day/period, if that has been taken already you should throw an error.

You can however have an extra level of protection in your code by using an index to ensure uniqueness across those columns. e.g.

```
create unique index class_idx on TABLE_NAME (class,period,day);
```

This will stop you from being able to insert 2 rows with the same class,period,day combination

Answer (score 1):

Create a key on the combination of these attributes (so called "composite key").

The "key" is a modeling term. The physical constraint that implements it is either PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint depending on whether the key is primary or alternate (respectively).

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE (
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (day, period, class)
);
```

BTW, under MySQL/InnoDB, the primary key is also a [clustering](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/) key.

The order of fields matters - a query can typically use only the *leading edge* of the index (which is automatically created under the key). I recommend reading [Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) to familiarize yourself with the structure and performance characteristics of indexes.

Don't just create a UNIQUE INDEX - use a proper constraint as shown above.

Comment: I don't want to think about the number of table splits with your clustering index.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Care to clarify?

Comment: The reason it's called a clustering index is that the database wants to arrange the rows in the order of the index.  So, using your index, we put some rows for Monday, Tuesday, etc.  Assuming an integer represents the day of the week, the rows are added at the end of the table.  When some more Monday rows are added, the database wants to put them before the Tuesday rows.  But there are already rows there.  So what can the database do?  It either splits the table, so it can insert the rows in the proper place, or it puts the rows at the end of the table.

Comment: (Comment continued)  If the database puts the rows at the end of the table, the clustering index has to jump around on the disk drive to retrieve the rows in cluster order.  No matter what the database does, the table will have to be reorganized on a periodic basis.

Comment: (Comment continued) That's why we tell people to use an auto-incrementing integer or long as the clustering key.  It minimizes table splits and table reorganizations.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc You are right but this is probably useful in a table with high traffic. With only 300 rows in this table, it won't matter much, if at all.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Yes I know what clustered tables are :) What I don't know is why you think that having two B-Trees (for surrogate primary key + natural alternate key) is better than having just one (for natural primary key).

Comment: If the primary index wasn't a clustering index, you'd have a point.  However, depending on the database engine we're talking about, there's no performance reason for the clustering index to be a B-Tree.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc **Every** index is a B-Tree (short of hash and bitmap indexes and some other specialized types...), including clustered index.